# Using datareader and navigating records

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ado.net

i have a treeview with nodes like 
desktop
laptop
printer etc...

I wrote code to get records each base on the click of the above node(desktop,laptop etc..)
code:

```
Private Sub tvMenu_AfterSelect(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles tvMenu.AfterSelect
'The event handler for clicking a node in the treeview
    If tpDeviceStore.Focus Then
        desktop()
        notebooks()
    End If
 End Sub
```

'Example of one node and how record is retrieve from Dbase

```
Private Sub desktop()

    If tvMenu.SelectedNode.Name = "ndDesktop" Then
        Dim con As New clsGlobals
        con.cnn.Open()
        Dim str1 As String = "select * from DeviceLogger where devType='Desktop' order by devSN desc"
        Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand(str1, con.cnn)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read()
            txtDT.Text = dr("devType").ToString
            txtMF.Text = dr("devManufacture").ToString
            txtMod.Text = dr("devModel").ToString
            txtSN.Text = dr("devSN").ToString
            txtRD.Text = dr("devRecieveDte").ToString
            txtST.Text = dr("devStatus").ToString
        End While
        DV = New DataView(DS.Tables("Devicelogger"))
        CM = CType(Me.BindingContext(DV), CurrencyManager)
        dr.Close()
        con.cnn.Close()
    Else
        txtDT.Text = String.Empty
        txtMF.Text = String.Empty
        txtMod.Text = String.Empty
        txtSN.Text = String.Empty
        txtRD.Text = String.Empty
        txtST.Text = String.Empty

        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

I want when a record is retrieve my first, previous, next and last button should navigate the fields.
Thanks to all in advance for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to be able to navigate the records, I'm going to recommend that you leverage data binding and the `CurrencyManager`. Now, you're going to have to take my solution and fit it into your code (well because I'm not a VB.NET programmer really), but I'm going to give you an example. The first thing you have to do is set up the data binding:

```
txtDT.DataBindings.Add("Text", _dataContext, "{FieldName}")
```

where `{FieldName}` is one of the fields in the `_dataContext`. Here `_dataContext` would be defined as a [field in the class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) like this:

```
private DataTable _dataContext;
```

The next thing we'll have to do is actually load the data. Instead of using a `SqlDataReader`, we're just going to `Fill` a `DataTable` so that the `CurrencyManager` can do the rest. The code to get the data may look like this:

```
var sql = "select * from DeviceLogger where devType='Desktop' order by devSN desc";
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    c.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, c);
    {
        _dataContext = new DataTable();
        _dataContext.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    }
}

_currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)this.BindingContext[_dataContext];
_currencyManager.Position = 0
```

where `_currencyManager` is also a private class field defined like this:

```
private CurrencyManager _currencyManager;
```

Now when you click the next button, you can do this:

```
var nxt = _currencyManager.Position + 1;
var cnt = _currencyManager.Count;

_currencyManager.Position = (nxt >= cnt) ? cnt : nxt;
```

and the data in the data bound text boxes will change automatically. Going previous might look like this:

```
var prev = _currencyManager.Position - 1;
_currencyManager.Position = (prev < 0) ? 0 : prev;
```

Now, if the `_dataContext` looks a little different for a different set of data, that's fine, you just have to data bind the controls again so they match the `_dataContext` of the `CurrencyManager`. At any rate, this is the most straight forward way to move back and forth in a listing of data whilst the controls change their values.